# Text in an input when clicked on a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need a solution for when clicking a link, a value must be inserted into an input, containing the name of the link that was clicked. I do not know how to do it. Can someone help me?

IT can be something in jQuery, JavaScript, PHP... More or less follows the example:

```html
<a href="#contato" target="_self" id="5" class="button" style="">botão</a>

<form method="post" action="" class="" >
    <input type="text" name="Button that was clicked" id="" value="id" >
</form>

if (id == 5) {
    id = 'text exemple'
};
```

Comment: you need to put an "onclick" on your anchortag and in javascript you put the text from the anchor tag in the input text, and to do that you must give your input text an ID so u can identify the input in javascript.

Comment: Could you link to an example so I can use it as a base? I'm kind of inexperienced

Comment: Hello, Welcome to **Stackoverflow** :D Please don't forget to mark any answer that helped you as approved answer by clicking the *check mark* positioned at the top left of each answer. This will help other users that have the same issue as you to find easly the solution. Note also that you'll receive **+2** reputation when you accept an answer. Welcome once again and glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript really don't work how you think. I recommend you some tutorial. This code is correct:

```
<a href="#contato" target="_self" onclick="writeText()" class="button">botão</a>
<form method="post" action="" class="" >
<input type="text" name="Button that was clicked" id="text">
</form>

<script>
function writeText() {
    document.getElementById('text').value = 'text exemple';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give an ID (YOURID) or class to your input first and then the solution in jQuery would be :

```
<script>
jQuery('#5').on("click",function() {
var idbutton = $(this).attr("href");
$('#YOURID').val(idbutton);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hello, first of all, I think you should follow some tutorials of
>   jQuery, that you'll find here fore example: [W3SCHOOL JQUERY](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)

Then to answer your question follow these steps:

1. Add the jQuery **CDN** to your **HTML

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

2. After that, you must select the **CLICKED LINK** so it's will be like this:

   `$("a").on("click"...`
3. Finally you must implement a function that will be executed when the link selected earlier is clicked:

   function(){
       var id=$(this).attr("id");

   ```
     if(id === "5" ){
           $("#inputResult").val('text exemple');
       };
   }
   ```

Finally it will give you the following demo:

```js
$("a").on("click",function(){
var id=$(this).attr("id");

  if(id === "5" ){
  $("#inputResult").val('text exemple');
 };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#contato" target="_self" id="5" class="button" style="">botão</a><br>
<a href="#contato" target="_self" id="6" class="button" style="">botã22222o</a>
<form method="post" action="" class="" >

<input type="text" name="Button that was clicked" id="inputResult" value="id" >

</form>
```

> PS: Note that the condition is `if(id === "5")` instead of `if(id ===
>   5)` we are not comparing the `id` to a number cause we're retreiving
>   the value of an attribute, and this value is a `string`. So we must
>   either convert the `id` to a number or compare it to `string` and this
>   is what I did

Answer (score 0):

ES6 Solution

```
<a href="#contato" onClick="changeValue()" target="_self" id="5" class="button" style="">botão</a>

<form method="post" action="" class="" >
    <input type="text" name="Button that was clicked" id="textfield" value="id" >
</form>

<script>
    let textVal = 'text example'
    let changeValue = () => {
        document.getElementById("textfield").value = textVal
    }
</script>
```